# WSO2 Api Manager 3.2.0 PostgreSQL issues

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to use WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0

I configured it on postgre by following this link https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-postgresql/#setting-up-postgresql

This id my `deployment.toml` configuration:

```
[database.apim_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.yyy.zz.ww:5432/api_mgr_apim_db"
#hostname = "xxx.yyy.zz.ww"
#port = "5432"
#name = "api_mgr_apim_db"
username = "wso2apimgr"
password = "wso2apimgr"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
pool_options.maxActive = "5"
pool_options.maxWait = "60000"
pool_options.minIdle = "1"
pool_options.maxIdle = "2"
pool_options.testOnBorrow = false
pool_options.validationQuery="SELECT 1; COMMIT"
pool_options.validationInterval="30000"
pool_options.defaultAutoCommit=false

[database.shared_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.yyy.zz.ww:5432/api_mgr_shared_db"
#hostname = "xxx.yyy.zz.ww"
#port = "5432"
#name = "api_mgr_shared_db"
username = "wso2apimgr"
password = "wso2apimgr"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
pool_options.maxActive = "5"
pool_options.maxWait = "60000"
pool_options.minIdle = "1"
pool_options.maxIdle = "2"
pool_options.testOnBorrow = false
pool_options.validationQuery="SELECT 1; COMMIT"
pool_options.validationInterval="30000"
pool_options.defaultAutoCommit=false

[database.local]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.yyy.zz.ww:5432/api_mgr_shared_db"
#hostname = "xxx.yyy.zz.ww"
#port = "5432"
#name = "api_mgr_shared_db"
username = "wso2apimgr"
password = "wso2apimgr"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
pool_options.maxActive = "5"
pool_options.maxWait = "60000"
pool_options.minIdle = "1"
pool_options.maxIdle = "2"
pool_options.testOnBorrow = false
pool_options.validationQuery="SELECT 1; COMMIT"
pool_options.validationInterval="30000"
pool_options.defaultAutoCommit=false
```

I put the postgreSQL driver in component/lib directory and I executed the postgre.sql script in my databases

When I start the server I get this error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:10,328] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} - Unable to create fixed remote mounts. org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. null
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.delete(HandlerManager.java:2653)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.delete(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:214)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.delete(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:443)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.delete(EmbeddedRegistry.java:851)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.delete(CacheBackedRegistry.java:595)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.deleteInternal(UserRegistry.java:879)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1100(UserRegistry.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$12.run(UserRegistry.java:854)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$12.run(UserRegistry.java:851)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.delete(UserRegistry.java:851)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.setupMounts(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:299)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:529)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.delete(MountHandler.java:490)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.delete(HandlerManager.java:2629)
    ... 53 more

TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:10,393]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} - Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:10,609]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JmxReporterBuilder} - Creating JMX reporter for Metrics with domain 'org.wso2.carbon.metrics'
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:10,613]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} - Started JMX reporter for Metrics
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:12,800]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} - Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:13,216]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} - Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:15,309]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} - User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:15,310]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} - User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,061]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.websocket.transport.WebsocketTransportSender} - WSS Sender started
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,065]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender} - Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,096]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender} - Pass-through HTTP Sender started...
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,097]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} - Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,262]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.config.ClientConnFactoryBuilder} - customSSLProfiles configuration is loaded from path: /opt/diomedee/wso2am-3.2.0/repository/resources/security/sslprofiles.xml
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,262]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.config.ClientConnFactoryBuilder} - HTTPS Loading custom SSL profiles for the HTTPS sender
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,432]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.config.ClientConnFactoryBuilder} - HTTPS Custom SSL profiles initialized for 1 servers
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,433]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} - Pass-through HTTPS Sender started...
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,437]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.websocket.transport.WebsocketTransportSender} - WS Sender started
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,454]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener} - Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,475]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpMultiSSLListener} - Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,632]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.config.ServerConnFactoryBuilder} - SSLProfile configuration is loaded from path: /opt/diomedee/wso2am-3.2.0/repository/resources/security/listenerprofiles.xml
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-19 18:22:16,827] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry} - Registry Exception occurred while executing the query org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: PooledConnection has already been closed.
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.SQLQueryProcessor.executeQuery(SQLQueryProcessor.java:239)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.queries.QueryProcessorManager.executeQuery(QueryProcessorManager.java:137)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.executeQuery(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2299)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils.getDirectArtifactPath(GovernanceUtils.java:851)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.handlers.MetaDataCacheHandler.clearPreFetchArtifact(MetaDataCacheHandler.java:72)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.handlers.MetaDataCacheHandler.put(MetaDataCacheHandler.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2505)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:958)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:705)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:591)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:840)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:816)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:813)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:813)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.populateConnectionProperties(CarbonServerManager.java:678)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:450)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

I tested this on postgreSQL 10 and postgreSQL 13 but in both cases as soon as I start the server I get the error and server doesn't start.

May anybody tell me how to solve the issue?

Angelo

**UPDATE**

As suggested I changed my `deployment.toml` by using separated DB for shared and user. Now my `deployment.toml` is:

```
[database.apim_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.yyy.zz.ww:5432/api_mgr_apim_db"
#hostname = "xxx.yyy.zz.ww"
#port = "5432"
#name = "api_mgr_apim_db"
username = "credentials"
password = "credentials"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
pool_options.maxActive = "20"
pool_options.maxWait = "60000"
pool_options.minIdle = "1"
pool_options.maxIdle = "10"
#pool_options.testOnBorrow = false
#pool_options.validationQuery="SELECT 1; COMMIT"
pool_options.validationInterval="30000"
#pool_options.defaultAutoCommit=false

[database.shared_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.yyy.zz.ww:5432/api_mgr_shared_db"
#hostname = "xxx.yyy.zz.ww"
#port = "5432"
#name = "api_mgr_shared_db"
username = "credentials"
password = "credentials"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
pool_options.maxActive = "20"
pool_options.maxWait = "60000"
pool_options.minIdle = "1"
pool_options.maxIdle = "10"
#pool_options.testOnBorrow = false
#pool_options.validationQuery="SELECT 1; COMMIT"
pool_options.validationInterval="30000"
#pool_options.defaultAutoCommit=false

[database.local]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.yyy.zz.ww:5432/api_mgr_carbon_db"
#hostname = "xxx.yyy.zz.ww"
#port = "5432"
#name = "api_mgr_shared_db"
username = "credentials"
password = "credentials"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
pool_options.maxActive = "20"
pool_options.maxWait = "60000"
pool_options.minIdle = "1"
pool_options.maxIdle = "10"
#pool_options.testOnBorrow = false
#pool_options.validationQuery="SELECT 1; COMMIT"
pool_options.validationInterval="30000"
#pool_options.defaultAutoCommit=false
```

But now i get this error:

```
TID: [-1234] [accountrecoveryendpoint] [2021-01-20 11:47:19,186]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} - Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/accountrecoveryendpoint].File[/opt/diomedee/wso2am-3.2.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/accountrecoveryendpoint]
TID: [-1] [] [2021-01-20 11:47:32,227]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService} - Starting polling event receivers
TID: [-1] [] [2021-01-20 11:47:52,556]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.AppDeployerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.service.SynapseAppDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
TID: [-1] [] [2021-01-20 11:47:52,603]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.service.CappDeploymentService,org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent,
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-20 11:48:19,172] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.dataaccess.TransactionManager} - Failed to start new registry transaction. org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [pool-111-thread-19] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 60 seconds, none available[size:20; busy:20; idle:0; lastwait:60000].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:712)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:83)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.beginTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:443)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:505)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.get(CacheBackedRegistry.java:175)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getInternal(UserRegistry.java:629)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$400(UserRegistry.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:609)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:606)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.get(UserRegistry.java:606)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.AsyncIndexer$IndexingTask.createIndexDocument(AsyncIndexer.java:242)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.AsyncIndexer$IndexingTask.run(AsyncIndexer.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-20 11:48:19,179] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.AsyncIndexer} - Error while indexing. Resource at path "/_system/config/identity/questionCollection"could not be indexedorg.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to start new registry transaction.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-20 11:48:19,190] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.dataaccess.TransactionManager} - Failed to start new registry transaction. org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [pool-111-thread-1] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 60 seconds, none available[size:20; busy:20; idle:0; lastwait:60000].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:712)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:83)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.beginTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:443)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.getTags(EmbeddedRegistry.java:1540)
```

May anybody, kindly, why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion create 2 separate databases for **SHARED_DB** + **WSO2CARBON_DB** and **APIM_DB**.

**SHARED_DB** stores API Manager related data and **SHARED_DB** stores registry and user management data. By default, **WSO2CARBON_DB** will be an embedded H2 database and it is not necessary to change it to another database

eg :  **SHARED_DB** --> `shared_db`
**APIM_DB**   --> `apim_db`
**CARBON_DB**   --> `carbon_db`

To create the necessary tables for shared_db execute the script of  `APIM_HOME//dbscripts/postgresql.sql`.

To create the necessary tables for carbon_db execute the script of  `APIM_HOME//dbscripts/postgresql.sql`.

> Note that `APIM_HOME//dbscripts/postgresql.sql` contains both Registry
> and User management tables. So we are using the same scripts.

To create the necessary tables for apim_db execute the script of  `APIM_HOME//dbscripts/apimgt/postgresql.sql`.

When configuring those DBs in APIM make sure that you specified the correct DB name in the configuration elements.

```
[database.apim_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.yyy.zz.ww:5432/apim_db"

[database.shared_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.yyy.zz.ww:5432/shared_db"

[database.local]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.yyy.zz.ww:5432/shared_db"
```

Comment: I updated my question. Now it's little bit better but I get another error

Comment: Are you running this in a distributed setup?

Comment: no; I simply unzipped the archive, configured the postgreSQL (and some other things) and started

Comment: Okey. Thanks for the reply. The recommended [maxActive](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance520/Setting+up+PostgreSQL) connections value is 80.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the same database is pointed to `SHARED_DB` and `CARBON_DB`. You can use the embedded H2 database for `CARBON_DB(database.local)` as it is not necessary to change it. Can try changing the `database.local` to use the H2 DB or create new database for CARBON_DB and startup the pack.

Refer the `Changing WSO2CARBON_DB to MySQL` section in [1]

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-mysql/

Comment: I updated my question. Now it's little bit better but I get another error

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the new issue which is,

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.dataaccess.TransactionManager} - Failed to start new registry transaction. org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [pool-111-thread-1] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 60 seconds, none available[size:20; busy:20; idle:0; lastwait:60000].
```

it looks like the connection pool is exhausted. Can you increase the maxActive connections value and recheck ?

```
#set this to a higher value ex: 50 which is the default value APIM
pool_options.maxActive = "50"
```

Comment: i can increase it... but we have 1 user (me) and i'm neither connected to the web interface.... it seems to me strange to consume 20 connection just only in starting phase. It seems to me something related to the DB handling....

Comment: Since this uses connection pooling, there can be instances where stale connections are not released properly. Can you try increasing the maxActive value to a value around 60-100?